# How can I control which fields to serialize with YAML

Tags: ruby, yaml

For instance,

```
class Point
  attr_accessor :x, :y, :pointer_to_something_huge
end
```

I only want to serialize x and y and leave everything else as nil.

Answer (score 25):

In Ruby 1.9, [`to_yaml_properties` is deprecated](https://github.com/tenderlove/psych/blob/1606060069c13b2bcdc672a1a0e89202a9eb5166/lib/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb#L392); if you're using Ruby 1.9, a more future proof method would be to use `encode_with`:

```
class Point
  def encode_with coder
    coder['x'] = @x
    coder['y'] = @y
  end
end
```

In this case that’s all you need, as the default is to set the corresponding instance variable of the new object to the appropriate value when loading from Yaml, but in more comple cases you could use `init_with`:

```
def init_with coder
  @x = coder['x']
  @y = coder['y']
end
```

Comment: FYI: If you overwrite `#init_with` for an `ActiveRecord::Base` subclass, remember to return `self`, otherwise any time you instantiate a model it will return nil.

Comment: What else does `encode_with` effect? `to_json` and friends as well?

Answer (score 8):

After an inordinate amount of searching I stumbled on this:

```
class Point
  def to_yaml_properties
    ["@x", "@y"]
  end
end
```

This method is used to select the properties that YAML serializes. There is a more powerful approach that involves custom emitters (in Psych) but I don't know what it is.

This solution only works in Ruby 1.8; in Ruby 1.9, `to_yaml` has switched to using Psych, for which Matt's answer using `encode_with` is the appropriate solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you want all fields but a few, you could do this

```
def encode_with(coder)
  vars = instance_variables.map{|x| x.to_s}
  vars = vars - ['@unwanted_field1', '@unwanted_field2']

  vars.each do |var|
    var_val = eval(var)
    coder[var.gsub('@', '')] = var_val
  end
end
```

This stops you from manually having to manage the list.  Tested on Ruby 1.9

Answer (score 1):

If you have a plenty of instance variables, you could use a short version like this one

```
def encode_with( coder )
  %w[ x y a b c d e f g ].each { |v| coder[ v ] = instance_variable_get "@#{v}" }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use #encode_with because #to_yaml_properties is deprecated:

```
def encode_with(coder)
  # remove @unwanted and @other_unwanted variable from the dump
  (instance_variables - [:@unwanted, :@other_unwanted]).each do |var|
    var = var.to_s                       # convert symbol to string
    coder[var.gsub('@', '')] = eval(var) # set key and value in coder hash
  end
end
```

or you might prefer this if eval is too dangerous and you only need to filter out one instance var. All other vars need to have an accessor:

```
attr_accessor :keep_this, :unwanted

def encode_with(coder)
  # reject @unwanted var, all others need to have an accessor
  instance_variables.reject{|x|x==:@unwanted}.map(&:to_s).each do |var|
    coder[var[1..-1]] = send(var[1..-1])
  end
end
```

Comment: Add some comments to your answer.

Answer (score -2):

I'd recommend adding a custom `to_yaml` method in your class that constructs the specific yaml format you want.

I know that `to_json` accepts parameters to tell it what attributes to serialize, but I can't find the same for `to_yaml`.

Here's the actual source for `to_yaml`:

```
# File activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb, line 653

  def to_yaml(opts = {}) #:nodoc:
    if YAML.const_defined?(:ENGINE) && !YAML::ENGINE.syck?
      super
    else
      coder = {}
      encode_with(coder)
      YAML.quick_emit(self, opts) do |out|
        out.map(taguri, to_yaml_style) do |map|
          coder.each { |k, v| map.add(k, v) }
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

So it looks like there may be an opportunity to set `opts` so that it includes specific key/value pairs in the yaml.