# YAML failing with enumerators

Tags: ruby, yaml

I'm writing a library in Ruby that uses random numbers. I've written the components so that `rand` is the default underlying generator, but sophisticated users may want to supply their own random implementation.  It's easy to wrap any implementation in an `Enumerator`, which gives a common interface using `.next` to access the generator no matter whose it is. (Note that `rand` does not natively provide `next`, hence the wrapper.)  In Ruby 2.7:

```
# File my_module.rb
module Demo
  U_GEN = Enumerator.produce(rand) { rand }  # wrap rand as enum

  class SomeThing
    def initialize(scale:, rng: U_GEN)
      @scale = scale
      @rng = rng
    end

    def triangle1
      @scale * Math.sqrt(@rng.next)
    end

    def triangle2
      @scale * (1.0 - Math.sqrt(@rng.next))
    end
  end
end
```

Most users will probably just instantiate `SomeThing.new(scale: whatever)`, but sophisticated users who want something other than `rand` can opt for `SomeThing.new(scale: whatever, rng: custom_generator)`.

For large products, I want to be able to control the configuration with YAML.  My problem is that a `YAML.dump` of a `SomeThing` object seems to want to generate the complete set of values for an `Enumerator`, as seen here:

```
require 'yaml'
require_relative 'my_module'

finite_enum = (1..9).map { |x| x / 10.0 }.each

this_works = Demo::SomeThing.new(scale: 42, rng: finite_enum)
puts "#{this_works.triangle1}\n"   # => 13.281566172707194

this_works_yaml = YAML.dump(this_works)  # can dump with a finite enum, but...

puts this_works_yaml
# Output...
#
# --- !ruby/object:Demo::SomeThing
# scale: 42
# rng:
# - 0.1
# - 0.2
# - 0.3
# - 0.4
# - 0.5
# - 0.6
# - 0.7
# - 0.8
# - 0.9

this_fails = YAML.load(this_works_yaml)
p this_fails
# Output...
#
# <Demo::SomeThing:0x00007fb01e88b0c8 @scale=42,
#        @rng=[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9]>

# rng is now an array, not an enumerator, so the following gives an
# "undefined method `next'" error trying to get the next random number
puts "#{this_fails.triangle1}"
```

With an infinite generator such as `U_GEN`, you can't even get the dump to work:

```
require 'yaml'
require_relative 'my_module'

actual_use_case = Demo::SomeThing.new(scale: 42)  # use default U_GEN for rng
puts "#{actual_use_case.triangle1}\n"

# If uncommented, the following goes to infinity and beyond!
# actual_use_yaml = YAML.dump(actual_use_case)
```

If anybody knows a magic incantation to dump/load an object that has an `Enumerator` as an instance variable so that the `Enumerator` is preserved rather than converted to an array of the values it produces, I'd be quite grateful.

---

Apologies for any confusion or misunderstandings from my first draft.  I hope that providing actual working code will clarify the question.

Comment: You can always make a [custom encoder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10629209/how-can-i-control-which-fields-to-serialize-with-yaml) for your class.

Comment: You really, *really* do not want `eval`. Stay far, far away from it. Instead use a custom encoder and save the parameters instead.

Comment: @tadman Since I haven't yet found *any* mechanism for dumping or loading Enumerators, I'm still not seeing how that would work.

Comment: You need to wrap it in your own class, and in that have a custom encoder.